# How can i get EF6 to remove an object from the database when it is removed from a collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 code first when amending a child collection then running Save, the save runs but the Db row are not deleted there just have there foreign key set to null.

Basic model

```
public class Building 
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   ICollection<BuildingFloors> BuildingFloors
}    

public class BuildingFloors
{
   int id
}
```

I am setting the cascade in the DBContext like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Building>()
                .HasMany(t => t.BuildingFloors)
                .WithOptional(d => d.Building)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Then when saving the collection i am clearing the current list.

```
building.BuildingFloors.Clear();
```

then re adding the new values.

```
foreach(var floor in FloorCollection)
{
   building.BuildingFloors.Add(buildingFloor);
}
```

How can i get EF to remove an object from the database when it is removed from the collection?

Comment: You cannot. But if you remove object from dbcontext it will be removed from collection too.

Comment: Btw. If you change relations to One-to-Many instead of zero/one-to-many, it will work out of the box.

Comment: Could you explain how I might do that?

Comment: You can do that by replacing ".WithOptional(d => d.Building)" with ".WithRequired(d => d.Building)". If a BuildingFloor can not exist without Building you should make this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmg. was right with the exception that i also needed to set the forign key relationship

so buildingfloors class needs to be

```
public class BuildingFloors
{
   int id

   //forgin key 
   int Building_Id
}
```

and the mapping needs to be

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Building>()
  .HasMany(t => t.BuildingFloors)
  .WithRequired()
  .HasForeignKey(t => t.Building_Id)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```